# Reverse circular tailwind spinner

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, css-animations

I'm trying to create a reverse circular tailwind spinner but I can't seem to get it right. The loader should start off filled with a gray color and loads as it changes to a light gray color. In the middle of the loader is a close button.

Here is what I have so far.

```
tailwind.config.js
```

```
extend: {
      animation: {
        'reverse-spin' : 'reverse-spin 6s linear infinite'
        
      },
      keyframes: {
        'reverse-spin': {
          from: {
            transform: 'rotate(360deg)'
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

My loader looks like this.

```
<div className="added-to-cart-modal-icon ml-auto w-9 h-9 relative cursor-pointer" onClick={Store.cart.hideCartModal}>
   <div className="spinner h-full w-full rounded-full border-2 border-l-primary-500 animate-reverse-spin"></div>
            <img
              src={CloseIcon}
              alt="close"
              className="absolute left-1/2 top-1/2 p-2  -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2"
            />
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div className="added-to-cart-modal-icon ml-auto w-9 h-9 relative cursor-pointer" onClick={Store.cart.hideCartModal}>
  <div className="spinner h-full w-full rounded-full border-2 border-l-primary-500 animate-reverse-spin"></div>
  <img
    src={CloseIcon}
    alt="close"
    className="absolute left-1/2 top-1/2 p-2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2"
  />
</div>
```